# NSEntityMigrationPolicy subclass methods not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am trying to migrate from one .xcdatamodel file to another. I have a NSEntityMigrationPolicy subclass, the name of which I have entered in xcode-> .xcmappingmodel file -> entity -> "custom Policy" field.

I run my app which successfully opens and runs the previous version of my data so I can only assume basic migration has worked. HOWEVER my NSEntityMigrationPolicy subclass methods are not being called so that I can run further migration code.

```
@implementation TestMigrationPolicy

- (BOOL)beginEntityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError * *)error
{
    NSLog(@"this log is never shown!!!!");
    return YES;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why my it might not be getting called? I am new to core data migration and I'm currently at a loss as to why this is not behaving as I feel it should.

If it helps, I am creating the persistent store like this..

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], 
                         NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                         nil];


NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
NSLog(@"storeUrl  %@", storeUrl);

if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this question is old but this may help others!

It's because you have the option *NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption* set - which means lightweight migration is being run, rather than using your mapping model. Remove this option, leaving * NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption* in place and all should work.

Comment: Ah, that's cool, thanks! … but what about if I also want automatic mapping to occur? So, I'm on model version 16. I want a manual migration from 15 to 16, but earlier migrations can be automatic.

Comment: Beware. For those who might come across this answer, it is not entirely accurate as far as I'm aware. According to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstoredescription/1640623-shouldinfermappingmodelautomatic) the automatic inference is a fall back if no mapping can be found. So likely the problem is somewhere else because if you have a mapping available that can be found, Core Data should use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. In my case this happens because Core Data is not able to found my compiled data mapping file (a file with 'cdm' extension) in the resulting application bundle. When I manually moved that file from nested bundle to the root of application bundle (MyApp.app\NestedBundle.bundle\MyMapping.cdm -> MyApp.app\MyMapping.cdm) everything worked fine. But such file layout violates current logic of application bundle structure, so I will try to make Core Data to see my cdm file in nested bundle as well.

**UPD:** It seems that the best solution is to use custom initialization for migration process. Very nice example can found here - http://media.pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/code/ProgressiveMigration/AppDelegate.m. I've adopted that code for searching in all bundles and it works fine.